# Can you give bottomTabNavigator in React Native a dark mode background color and a light mode background color

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I am trying to make my bottom tab Navigator dark mode compatible.... however it seems to ignore the color given first and just uses the `#111827` for light and dark mode, so I end up with just a dark background bottom tab. It doesn't throw any errors.

```
export default function MainNavigator() {
const colorMode = useColorMode();
  return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Daily Care"
        screenOptions={({ route, colorMode }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Daily Care') {
              return <IconDailyCare color={color} />
            } else if (route.name === 'Learning') {
              return <IconLearning color={color} />
            } else if (route.name === 'Check-In') {
              return <IconCheckIn color={color} />
            } else if (route.name === 'Account') {
              return <IconAccount color={color} />
            }
          },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "#F4AC94",
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#80A1AC",
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: colorMode === 'light' ? '#fff' : '#111827',
            borderTopColor: colorMode === 'light' ? '#fff' : '#111827',
          },

        })}
      >
```

I'm using nativebase which is where the `useColorMode()` hook comes from.

Answer (score 0):

import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native';

const scheme = useColorScheme();

scheme === 'dark' ? backgroundColor1 : backgroundColor2